# Separate multiple JSON data in R

Tags: json, r, igraph

I am newbie of R and working on the below JSON file (snippet of head and relevant code example).

```
{"mdsDat":{"x":[0.098453,-0.19334,-0.23836,-0.28512,0.010195,0.14132,-0.026636,-0.17141,
0.082936,-0.030503,0.22893,0.097832,0.19978,0.048286,0.050141,0.026101,-0.10637,0.040702,
0.013531,0.013531],"y":[-0.21144,-0.25048,0.14525,-0.06405,0.16668,-0.066238,-0.23403,
0.17033,-0.037128,-0.019674,0.0089501,0.0069049,0.10143,-0.14445,0.052727,0.15911,0.049328,
0.074852,0.045969,0.045969],"topics":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20],
"Freq":[16.358,13.397,12.979,10.383,7.5134,7.16,6.1765,4.9584,4.6035,3.4624,3.4249,3.0709,
1.8512,1.8512,1.4977,0.90723,0.23895,0.16034,0.0031352,0.0031352],
"cluster":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]},
"tinfo":{"Term":["equation","equations","mathematics","beauty","mathematical","people",
"beautiful","explain","world","time","understand","science","things","meaning","language",
"symbols","simple","life","nature","interesting","art","agree","movie","find","numbers",
"explore","mass","relationship","video","scientists","agree","scientists","amazing","learn",
"apply","artistic","common","fear","beautiful","mathematics","study","mathematical","science",
"meaning","physics","gravity","exchange","math","world","future","explained","sense",
"process","words","equations","experience","move","faster","eyes","fall","nature","power",
"human","exam","things","answer","people","world","ways","truth","equations","video",
"balance","painting","space"
...
"token.table":{"Term":["0","1","2","2","abstract","abstract","addition","admire","agree",
"amazing","answer","answer","apple","application","applied","applied","apply","art","artist",
"artist","artistic","arts","balance","balance","balance","beautiful","beautiful","beautiful",
"beautiful","beauty","beauty","bring","bring","bunch","bunch","calculate","calculation",
"collings","collings","collings","common","complex","complex","complex","contact","curiosity",
"curiosity","daily","difficult","discover","documentary","documentary","documentary","earth",
"earth","einstein","energy","energy","english","english","enjoy","enjoy","enjoy","equation",
"equation","equation","equation","equation","equations","equations","equations","equations",
"exam","exam","examination","examination","exchange","exchange","exchange","experience",
"experience","explain","explained","explained","explore","eyes","eyes","fact","fall","famous",
"famous","faster","faster","fear","feel","film","film","find","find","force","formula","formula","found",
...
"work","world","world","world","worlds","years","years"],"Topic":[8,5,11,13,8,10,5,4,1,1,2,
15,9,10,9,12,1,3,4,9,1,5,2,4,10,1,4,7,14,2,6,3,15,10,15,
...
,16,3,7,2,14,2,5,1,8,4,9,10,15,1,2,14,9,11,13],"Freq":[0.97036,0.9702,0.75081,0.25027,0.22141,
0.77494,0.97584,0.96609,0.99493,0.98083,0.73954,0.24651,0.99013,0.
...
```

In the situation of the project, I have created a variable of `getJSONfield` as below,

```
getJSONfield <- json %>%       
    spread_values(jsonList = jstring("token.table")) %>%  
    select(jsonList)
```

Also, it returns a JSON list something like this

```
jsonNodes
1 list(Term = list("0", "1", "1", "2", "Data of JSON"), 
       Topic = list(9, 1, 10,"Data of JSON"), 
       Freq = list(0.99834, "Data of JSON"))
```

And, I have to separate the multiple variables (i.e. Term, Topic and Freq) as head and edge of network diagram. Something that I would like to use the JSON data for:

```
jsonNode <-lapply(json$**topic**, header=T, as.is = T)
jsonTermsLinkS <- lapply(json$**term**, header=T, as.is=T)
jsonTermsLinkE <- lapply(json$**freq**, header=T, as.is=T)
```

But, first, I need to separate or call them successfully. Can anyone have any idea or advise on this?

Great thanks if someone help me!

Comment: could you please show how to replicate the data that you're working with?

Comment: @e.wong Can you provide a bit more information -- how is the `json` variable defined above? It would help if you could also post an example of the JSON file you are attempting to parse.

Comment: Also, as a side note, I would recommend avoiding the use of camel-case for variable and function names. Most coding standards for R (e.g. [Hadley's](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Style.html)) encourage the use of low case variable names, e.g. `get_json_field`.

Comment: I am using the json which generates from LDAvis and it contains a large json data on it. For more detail, you can check it on https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7Msx7w5qze9SDdHdW9MOGJuUTg.

Comment: @KeithHughitt: unfortunately R doesn't have a single coding standard. Google, for example, suggests the use of camel case --> [link](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml)

Comment: Ah right - for some reason I thought Hadley and Google had the same suggestions for variable names. Thanks for reminding me! In that case, I suppose you can pick whichever standard you prefer, e.wong.

Comment: @KeithHughitt so does this case can be solved by separating the json variables? is is possible to separate? because I have tried `lapply` or `sapply` and they are not working...

Comment: @e.wong Still need some more information to help answer your question - see my first comment above.

Comment: To OP - I edited your question, adding the json snippet using Google Drive link. By network diagram, I assume you mean the igraph package. Please adjust as needed.

Comment: @Parfait Yes, I am using igraph package